# Getting error while running spark job for cassandra connector - Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to write statements to test.events

Tags: eclipse, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to insert data to `Cassandra` using a `Apache Spark` job in `eclipse`. I am able to run my sample code but facing issue with complex table design.

Can someone please help how to resolve this issue?

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to write statements to test.events.
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(TableWriter.scala:167)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(TableWriter.scala:135)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:111)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:110)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.closeResourceAfterUse(CassandraConnector.scala:140)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withSessionDo(CassandraConnector.scala:110)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter.write(TableWriter.scala:135)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.streaming.DStreamFunctions$$anonfun$saveToCassandra$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DStreamFunctions.scala:54)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.streaming.DStreamFunctions$$anonfun$saveToCassandra$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DStreamFunctions.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
    ... 3 more
```

Comment: Can you please edit question and include your scala code; also walk through your schema.

Comment: Go to the executor that is throwing the exception and get that log. This is just the "Failed all attempts Message". You need to go to the machine at it's source and get the error there.

Comment: I am running this code from eclipse, can you please help tell me , where can i find executor logs?

Comment: @pseudoAj 
My schema Create Table test (
//column declaration,
PRIMARY KEY( A, Date, B, C,D))
   WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (Date ASC,B ASC, C ASC)
   AND COMPRESSION = { 'sstable_compression' : 'SnappyCompressor'} ; 

In java code I am calling,
CassandraStreamingJavaUtil.javaFunctions(data).writerBuilder("test", "events", CassandraJavaUtil.mapToRow(Pojo.class)).saveToCassandra();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the keys first and see if only one key works or not. I can see you are using date, so then it can be unique, just try to insert few records at first, If that does not work, see in date, If there is any problem with the date formatting you are using, because it can cause you many problem, I once had a similar issue, and I checked my date, somehow during manipulation, it became 12-00-2012, so because of that cassandra was throwing error.

If sample code works that means there should not be any issue with the configuration.